# Remove dot after footnote marker

Tags: footnotes

I have a problem with the numbering of my footnotes.
All of my footnotes have a dot after the footnote marker :

[image]

Now, the editor that will publish my thesis told me to remove the dot after the numbering. 
Any suggestions how I could do this?

Here part of my code :

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\baretabulars
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}
Cette méthode procède par une analyse de correspondances ...\footnote{Pour des informations complémentaires, ...}
\end{document}
```

I have to work with the `dgruyter` stylesheet ; you can find it here : [dgruyter.sty](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s1tv0eg9ejluqe/dgruyter.sty?dl=0)

I'd be grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: The file dgruyter.sty doesn't seem to be accessible on dropbox.

Comment: Please also tell us how the footnote markers are supposed to look like according to your publisher. So far, all we know is that no dot should follow the footnote number. But what about its size and position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of French babel.

```
\renewcommand*{\dotFFN}{}
```

Will remove it.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

This code redefines the footnote numbering format: as a number without a dot after it. You write this line before
  `\begin{document}`

Comment: Could you explan why this solves the problem (and maybe complete the code example)?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: The OP has mentioned that s/he uses the `babel` package with `french` as the main language. This combination is responsible for the appearance of the footnote markers in the footer. Have you ascertained whether your suggestion works with babel/french?